# Setting state conditionally based on prevState in useEffect cause exponential re-render

Tags: reactjs

Simple functional stateful component with useEffect hook. Main purpose of this is to listen clicks and toggle profile menu based on event.target is equal to ref.current.

```
e.target === ref.current
```

It works as expected however if I add

```
&& !menuVisible
```

to that condition (show menu only if its hidden) it causes exponential re-render with every click. Start with one render on one click, two on second, four on third, eight on fourth..

```
const Profile: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (e: Event) => {
      e.target === ref.current && !menuVisible
        ? setMenuVisible(true)
        : setMenuVisible(false);
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", e => handleClick(e));
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", e => handleClick(e));
    };
  });

  return (
    <ProfileWrapper>
      <ProfileMedailone ref={ref} />
      {menuVisible && <ProfileMenu />}
    </ProfileWrapper>
  );
};
```

Should I do better job in cleanup phase or where is the catch?

Comment: 1.) Add an empty dependency array to your `useEffect()`
2.) Change your click event to `const handleClick = (e: Event) => { if (e.target === ref.current) setMenuVisible(current => !current); };`
3.) remove the anonymous function in your add/removeEventListeners and just pass in `handleClick` as the method

Comment: Thank you sir! I just kept else statement `target !== ref.current setMenuVisible(false)` for hiding menu, when click is anywhere else. But your comment solved my problem.

Comment: @David Zoufaly can you please add your final and working code as an answer here? Would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (e: Event) => {
      if (e.target === ref.current) {
        setMenuVisible(current => !current);
      } else if (
        e.target === ref2.current ||
        e.target === ref2.current?.children[1] ||
        e.target === ref2.current?.children[2]
      ) {
        setMenuVisible(true);
      } else {
        setMenuVisible(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
```